# Reading username and password sent from and Android app into my WCF REST Service?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest

My current WCF REST Method is defined as:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{username}/{password}", ResponseFormat =                   
                                                        WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string Login(string username, string password);
```

An android client app is going to connect to the service, let's say it is http://service.com/login.svc/login...

But I don't want the username and password to be passed in the url like I have specified in the UriTemplate.  How can I receive the username and password from the android app into my service, or better yet, how can I change my login method to retrieve the username and password in some POST parameters that I can process in my login function and validate the user against a sql membership database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have done this via using the "Authorization" header.  The clients pass along an encrypted set of credentials and we generate a token for them on our side.  Here is an example of the BeginRequest method of an HttpModule that handles authentication.  We use a custom principal to handle the token:

```
 private void BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (null == HttpContext.Current || String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (Int32)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        Regex matcher = new Regex(WfmConfigurationManager.GetAppSetting("AuthenticationPath"));

        if (!matcher.IsMatch(context.Request.Url.ToString(),0))
        {
            String authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
            IIdentity tokenIdentity = new TokenIdentity(authHeader);

            if (!tokenIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (Int32)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            }

            IPrincipal tokenPrincipal = new TokenPrincipal(tokenIdentity, TokenAuthentication.GetRolesForUser(tokenIdentity));
            HttpContext.Current.User = tokenPrincipal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have sample code that you can provide?  This is where I am stuck, I have no idea how to set/get the Authorization Header? Basically, where do I start?

Comment: I added some code above from an HttpModule.  You can implement a custom principal as you see fit.

Comment: Adam, thanks for the code snippet.  A few questions:  Where do I implement this and when do I call it? Also, do I have to make any changes to my config files.  This is an internet service that will be accessible from all types of devices.

Comment: This is from within an HttpModule, see this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673(v=VS.100).aspx.  You will have to register the module in your web.config